# TFS to check in code and copy to webserver in one action

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Right now my workflow is to make code changes to my local code, test it locally then check the code into TFS via Pending Changes tab THEN use the Copy Website tool to copy code I just checked in to the actual webserver. There has to be a way to do this in one step but I can't find how do to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider a Build Server and Continuous Integration. The idea is that whenever someone makes a commit to the source control, the build server will get the latest version of the code, run the unit and integration tests that you have written and automatically deploy it to your web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use TFSBuild or another build server. If you are already familiar with TFS you are probably better just using TFS build unless you have tons of time to spend on this.

Basically, you setup a build controller, then you create a build definition for your project. This can be done in Visual studio. Not sure about setting up the build controller as this was done by the dev ops guy in my case, but a quick google search should show you how.

I found this guide which might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449957.aspx